# shadowCamera does not follow SpotLigth rotation

Tags: three.js

I have an issue with a spotLight. I have enabled shadowMap , I can see my shadows and everything works fine
. My issue comes when I start rotating the spotLight ( the one casting shadows) to aim at a moving target. Shadow casting still works inside the original spoltLight frustrum, but does not outside of that frustrum. 
I tried to animate spotLight.shadowCamera.rotation and even then, the shadow map stays static.
I also tried to update camera matrix each frame width spotLight.updateMatrix. --> no succees either
Am I missing something ?

in this jsfiddle , I am trying to animate the spotLight target position.

```
light.target.position.set(Math.sin(clock.getElapsedTime())*50,0,0);
```

but nothing moves .... 
why is that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/gui2one/95t964o0/5/

Comment: Please show your code, and preferably provide a jsfiddle. Here is a template: http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/.

Comment: Hi again ^^ thank you for the advice. I didn't know jsfiddle . it's pretty useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but I think your mistake is considering the target a position. The target must be an instance of an Object3D (class for all objects in three.js).

That's why updating the target's position doesn't have any effect. However, as you say, if you move the light, shadows are rendered properly, like you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abadabanades/95t964o0/9/

I just set the camera position a bit further and move the light in the render loop:

```
light.position.set( Math.sin(clock.getElapsedTime())*20, 20, 20);
```

And as far as I understand, you want the light (whether moving or not) to always point at a target. For achieving that, you must just specify the object (mesh in your case) as the target of the light (and not assigning it a position). Three.js will do the work for you and update the position automatically.

```
light.target = mesh;
```

And then, if you simply move the object in the rendering loop, the light will follow it automatically, like you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/abadabanades/95t964o0/13/

```
mesh.position.set( Math.sin(clock.getElapsedTime())*10, 0, 0);
```

I hope this helps you, in case not, can you calrify your question a bit more?

Comment: yes I think my main mistake was to consider light.target as a simple Vector3 ... now I get it , thank you

Comment: For everyone else's benefit, this answer has errors. The target was already an instance of `Object3D`. _The problem was that the target was not in the scene graph._ `scene.add( light.target ).` An alternate way to achieve that is to reassign `light.target` to be an object in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add light.target as a child of the scene.

```
scene.add( light.target );
```

If, instead, you had an object in your scene as the target, you could use this pattern:

```
scene.add( myObject );
spotLight.target = myObject;
```

For further information, see the three.js github post https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5555.

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/8

three.js r.69